# How to conditionally load `tikz` and draw a TikZ diagram when `preview` is not loaded

Tags: tikz-pgf, auctex, preview

How can I conditionally load `tikz` and draw a TikZ diagram only when `preview` is not loaded, i.e., AUCTeX is not generating images for other things (e.g., mathematical formulas)?

MWE:

```
 \documentclass{amsart}
 \usepackage{tikz} %*
 \begin{document}
 \[ a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \]
 \begin{figure}[htbp]
 \begin{tikzpicture} %*
 \draw (0, 0) -- (1, 1); %*
 \end{tikzpicture} %*
 \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

I'd like to exclude the lines with `%*` when AUCTeX generates images.

*Addendum*: AUCTeX loads `preview` by using `\AtBeginDocument`, like this:

```
 latex -ini -interaction=nonstopmode "&latex" prv_hoge.ini "\nonstopmode\nofiles\PassOptionsToPackage{active,tightpage,auctex}{preview}\AtBeginDocument{\ifx\ifPreview\undefined\RequirePackage[displaymath,floats,graphics,textmath,sections,footnotes]{preview}[2004/11/05]\fi}" "\input" mwe.tex
```

So branching by using `\@ifpackageloaded` in the preamble doesn't quite work.  What's an alternative?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\@ifpackageloaded{preview}{}{}`.

### References:

- [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
 
 \makeatletter
     \@ifpackageloaded{preview}{%
     }{%
         \usepackage{tikz}%
     }%
 \makeatother
 
 \begin{document}
 \[ a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \]
 \begin{figure}[htbp]
 \begin{tikzpicture} %*
 \draw (0, 0) -- (1, 1); %*
 \end{tikzpicture} %*
 \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```